# Why does the exponent operator give off a float rounding error

Tags: python, complex-numbers

When you try to get the square root of -1 using the exponent operator:

```
>>> (-1)**0.5    
(6.123233995736766e-17+1j)
```

Why do we get this insignificant real part (still not 0)? What are the operations done by the exponent operator that leads to the float precision error?

What I am trying to get at is how the ** approximate the answer, not to actually get the right answer.

Comment: It's zero to seventeen decimal places, that's pretty good!

Comment: Expect rounding error unless you have specific knowledge that an operation won't produce it.

Comment: try using sqrt from cmath https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html#module-cmath

Comment: Let's make sure that we solve your actual problem -- why is the difference important to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: `**` doesn't know that `sqrt(-1) == j`; it just jumps right into the trigonometry that lets you compute the value of any negative number raised to a fractional power.

Comment: @chepner that might just be the answer I'm after, if you could provide an example :)

Comment: See https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Objects/complexobject.c#l109 for the code that ultimately gets called.